# How to add or manipulate RenderTransform in automatically-added ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf

I'm assigning a `List<Foo>` to an `ItemsControl`'s `ItemSource`.  The `ItemsControl` is wrapping each `Foo` in a `ContentPresenter`.

I'm accessing each `ContentPresenter` when the `Canvas` in which they appear is loaded or resized.  I would like to add a `TransformGroup` to each `ContentPresenter`.

I could probably do this the first time the `Canvas` is loaded, but I'd like to know whether there is a preferred way.  Is there a way to catch when the `Foo` is wrapped and add the `TransformGroup` then, before the `Canvas` loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to modify the `ContentPresenter` would to define an `ItemContainerStyle` for the `ItemsControl`. If you want to add a `TransformGroup` to it, you'll have to do this programmatically by for example handle the `Loaded` event:

```
private void ContentPresenter_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)sender;
    // add transforms...
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ContentPresenter_Loaded" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

The other option is to create a custom `ItemsControl` and override the `GetContainerForItemOverride()` method where the `ContentPresenter` is created:

```
public class CustomItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)base.GetContainerForItemOverride();
        // add transforms...

        return cp;
    }
}
```